# Why my pc doesn't display the boot menu to choose an OS when I start the pc?

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, partitioning, operating-systems

I originally had a Windows OS and I wanted to also have a Linux OS. So I added Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows. However, when I start my pc, it doesn't display the boot menu and goes on the Windows OS immediately.

I tried to display the boot menu from Ubuntu : for that I edited the `/etc/default/grub` file by changing `hidden` to `menu` in the line `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` and then did `sudo update-grub`to save changes. But it didn't work.

I tried to display the boot meny from Windows : for that I went to the bios and tried to configure the UEFI to start from Ubuntu in the boot order to make Grub first position but I cannot do that cause it don't show me Grub.

How can I display the Grub menu to choose between Windows/Ubuntu when I start my pc ?

[my partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37tdS.png)

Ubuntu is on the partition number 9 of the image above.

PS : Sorry for the image being in French. I think it's still understandable though.

Comment: I think I have the same problem. I will try some solutions and let you know if it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you entirely sure that the disk you are booting from is the disk which grub is installed too? How exactly did you create your dualboot? Are both OS' installed to the same disk, or to two different disks? If it is the latter, then I suggest modifying your boot order to increase the priority of the grub partition.

Please use a live disk to double check exactly where your grub install is located (via GParted or other) and that the same disk is the one being booted from.

Comment: I have only one SSD disk in which I have a partition for Windows and an another one for Ubuntu. So both OS are indeed installed in the same disk. I edited my post to add an image showing all my partitions on my single disk.

Comment: How can I know if the disk my pc is booting from is the one grub is installed in it ?

Comment: What a mess. Why do you have so many partitions? I think you have done something incorrectly during your installation. A default windows install has 3 partitions.

Comment: You have an excessive amount of partitions likely due to misconfig during install. I see only a single FAT32 partition of 512m, at beginning of disk suggesting that this is indeed the bootsector being used. Why on earth it is assigned a drive letter I do not know. This sector could actually contain an EFI grub bootloader, but like I said, you really need to run GParted from inside a live disc to find out and be sure,any boot partitions should look like [this](https://imgur.com/raN9TGW), and I notice you have at least two 512mb partitions. Its possible you have installed a duplicate bootloader.